# Open with file explorer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Goal: Allow users in the "Visitors" group to utilise "Open With File Explorer"

To note: Owners can use the option "Open with File explorer" so I do not believe this issue to be related to how webdav is setup on the users machine. The Visitors Group has Read and Limited Access permissions applied to it.

I've applied the relevant permissions in the "Read" permissions so that users can view the document libraries contents and use the "Open with file explorer" option. This works on our development environment.

When doing the same on our production environment members of the owners group can use the "Open with file explorer" option whereas members of the Visitors group cannot. The users can view the document library and I've confirmed multiple times that they have the same permissions in SharePoint.

I've seen two types of error message which are:

[image]

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the pre requisite for the best experience with sharepoint:

1. Ensure the site is in trusted site
2. Use IE 32 bit
3. Ensure Office 32 bit is installed (not 64)

**Troubleshooting suggestions:**

1/ What about the site permission ? Does the have read access on the site itself ? Not only the library

2/ Create a new site where you set full control to your users, create a library or access the existing one "shared documents" => is the windows explorer working ?